# C# String.Contains() malfunction?

Tags: c#, string, contains

I am trying to check whether a string contains a specific string or not.

Briefly, here is my code (which is a small part of the program where I omitted irrelevant codes) :

```
string y = someValue;
for(string x in someCollection)
            {
                if (x.Contains(y))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(x + " Contains " + y);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(x + " Does Not Contain " + y);
                }
            }
```

However, this is what I get as the result:

```
"Alligator" Contains "Alligator"
"Loves" Does Not Contain "Love"
"To Eat You" Does Not Contain "You"
```

So, how come!?! Contains() returns true only when both strings are the exact matches?? Something is not right here...

ps. the string x and y were read from a text file and have been through some text cutting process, if that would help...

Comment: Are your sample strings the *exact* strings you're matching? I suspect that you have some Unicode strings that print out the same but are composed of different characters.

Comment: The text in the file was the exact string. A record I read this out is something like this:

"You"|"Alligator"|"Love" "Alligator"|"Loves"|"To Eat You"

Comment: @Robert Levy @Gabe Yes, I suspect the same thing. So, how can I check such thing? Is the problem has to do with the encoding format in my text file? (which I simply type it up in NotePad and save it to my program)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your output is correct.  Your expectation is wrong.  Your confusion is over the quote characters.  `"Loves"` really does not contain `"Love"`, but it does contain `"Love`.

Comment: Wow, I'd have to admit, nice catch.

Comment: Ahhhh, crap! This is quite embarrassing. Haha! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hah! Nice attention to detail.